# Stop \r from echoing

Tags: r

I have a file that contains random text. I'll call that text.txt

I used this code:

```
readfile <- read_file("text.txt")
```

When I type readfile into the console in rstudio, so:

```
>readfile
```

I obtain a result that that looks like:

```
\r\r\n random sentence. Blah blah blah.
Blah blah \r\r\n blah blah. \r\r\n blah.
```

This is probably happening due to spacing. The double \r is causing issues for me and I do not know how to remove this repetition of the \r. I was wondering if there was a way to remove one \r,
so basically:

```
\r\n random sentence. Blah blah blah.
Blah blah \r\n blah blah. \r\n blah.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with `gsub` and a regular expression.

```
Text = "\r\r\n random sentence. Blah blah blah.
Blah blah \r\r\n blah blah. \r\r\n blah."

Text2 = gsub("\r\r+", "\r", Text)

Text2
[1] "\r\n random sentence. Blah blah blah.\nBlah blah \r\n blah blah. \r\n blah."
cat(Text2)
  random sentence. Blah blah blah.
Blah blah   blah blah.   blah.
```

I used "\r\r+" so that it would also cover the case that there are more than two consecutive \r's.